# changing case of returned string in PHP_FUNCTION() C++

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

i want to create an extension for php with visual studio 2010 , i am beginner in c++.
my last function in C++ is :

```
PHP_FUNCTION(DoubleUp){
    char* text;
    int len;
    char string[255];
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &text) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_STRING("Invalid Parameters",true);
    } 
      len = sprintf(string,"echo 'hello %.78s'", text);
      RETURN_STRINGL(string,len, 1);
}
```

and in php i use :

```
echo DoubleUp('sss');
```

but output is : `echo 'hello Ð«õ'`
that should be : `echo 'hello sss'`
argument is a very long string .
now i don't know what should i do .
thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that `zend_parse_parameters` returns a `zval` if you specify `"z"` in the "type specifier" (the third parameter of `zend_parse_parameters`).

To get the correct string you can get the string directly using "s":

```
if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &text, &len) == FAILURE) {
```

In that case you have to supply the pointer to the `char*` for the string plus a pointer to an `int` to hold the string length.

The second solution is to use the `zval` correctly and get the string out of the `zval`:

```
zval* text;
int len;
char string[255]      
if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "z", &text) == FAILURE) { 
    /* ... */ 
}

// cast the value to string
convert_to_string(text);

// get the string value with the Z_STRVAL_P macro (Z_STRLEN_P for the length)
len = sprintf(string,"echo 'hello %.78s'", Z_STRVAL_P(text));
```